# so what is the average of the sequence made from $\cos(2)$

Tags: calculus, real-numbers, normal-number

so what is the average of the sequence made from cos(2)?

$\cos(2)=0.4161468365471423869975682295007621897660...$

the first number in the sequence is the first number in the decimal expansion until it hits a $0$
so $f(1)=4161468365471423869975682295$

The next number is the next number in the expansion

$f(2)=762189766$

$f(3)=771$

$f(4)=7554489$

You start the next number every time there is a $0$

If $\cos(2)$ is a normal number $0$ should be $10$% of the number expansion

My question is what's the average of $f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),...$ or what is the limit of $(f(1)\times f(2)\times f(3)\times f(4)\times f(5)\times f(6)\times ...\times f(n))^{1/n}$ as n goes to infinty.

big numbers a rarer than small numbers witch should make it possible to converge.

Comment: What is a normal number? Would you define $\frac 13$ as normal number also? There are no zeros in its decimal expansion.

Comment: a normal number is a number that has all possible number sequences like pi we think it's a normal number we think it has everyone's phone number in it @PierreCarre

Comment: @PierreCarre it's a type of number most numbers are normal all normal numbers have all possible finite digits in them so 1/3 isn't a normal number

Comment: $\cos2$ is _simply normal_ if each individual digit appears 10% of the time in the limit; it is _normal_ if every finite sequence of digits occurs with the expected frequency (so for example 823 appears 0.1% of the time). There seems to be no reason not to believe that $\cos2$ is normal, which would imply that the average of the OP's sequence is $\frac12$. But proving normality is notoriously difficult—no natural constant is known to be normal, even though most constants are.

Comment: Assuming almost-independence, the "length" of $f(n)$ would asymptotically follow a geometric distribution with $p=\frac{9}{10}$, whereas $f(n)$ given the length $L$ is at least $10^{L-1}$. So, those exceptionally large chunks will spoil the arithmetic mean $(f(1)+\dots+f(n))/n$ and we may expect that this diverges as $n\to\infty$. For the geometric mean, I guess that it will converge by a similar reasoning. Of course, all these speculations are based on the assumption that is much stronger than the mere block-normality of $\cos(2)$, which is totally elusive at the present time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fun of it, I made some calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & \text{arithmetic mean} & \text{geometric mean} \\
 50 &  9.3630\times 10^{51} & 5.7203\times 10^{11} \\
 100 & 4.6815\times 10^{51} & 7.4872\times 10^{10} \\
 150 & 3.1214\times 10^{51} & 1.5380\times 10^{11} \\
 200 & 2.3410\times 10^{51} & 6.5607\times 10^{10} \\
 250 & 1.8728\times 10^{51} & 5.7707\times 10^{10} \\
 300 & 2.8256\times 10^{61} & 1.2065\times 10^{11}
\end{array}
\right)$$